# \fancyhead[C] does not display correctly with ACM template

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, acm

I am composing a paper submitted to ACM, and I am using the template provided here: https://github.com/acmccs/format/blob/master/ccs-template.tex. The problem I am having is for the following code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf, anonymous]{acmart}

\fancyhf{} % Remove fancy page headers 
\fancyhead[C]{Anonymous submission \#9999 to ACM CCS 2019} % TODO: replace 9999 with your paper number
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\setcopyright{none} % No copyright notice required for submissions
\acmConference[Anonymous Submission to ACM CCS 2019]{ACM Conference on Computer and Communications Security}{Due 15 May 2019}{London, TBD}
\acmYear{2019}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false, printccs=true, printfolios=true} % We want page numbers on submissions
```

it is supposed to display the `\fancyhead` content in the middle of the page header, however, it displays the paper title on the left, and the content in `\acmConference` on the right. Is there anything else I need to do to make it appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`acmart` resets the fancy headers at `\begin{document}`, so your redefinition is overriden.  It *is* possible to override it again, but I wonder why would anyone want it since ACM wants the papers title in the left header.

Anyways, if you want to override the class settings, put fancyheader code *after* `\begin{document}`.

Comment: if you look in the example PDF from the link, it has "Anonymous submission xxxx to ACM CCS 2019" in the middle of the header. I guess for anonymous submission for review, they want this header, and for formal publication, they want the other. This solves my problem, thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, I have to put both \fancyhf{} and \fancyhead after \begin{documnet}, otherwist the middle header will overlap with the left header.

Comment: Yes, since `\fancyheader[C]{...]` adds the center headers, but does not delete the left one.  `\fancyhf{}` deletes all headers.